# Why can the del operator cross product a triple integral be placed inside the triple integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, cross-product, curl

Consider the (electric) vector field

$$\pmb{E}(\pmb{r})=k_e\iiint_V \frac{\rho(\pmb{r_s})}{\lVert \pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s} \lVert^2}\frac{\pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s}}{\lVert \pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s} \lVert}d\tau\tag{1}$$

where $\pmb{r_s}$ is the position vector of a source charge, $\rho(\pmb{r_s})$ is the charge-per-unit-volume at $\pmb{r_s}$, and $\pmb{r}$ is the fixed position vector of a field point.

Suppose we want to calculate $\nabla\times \pmb{E}$.

Here is one way that I saw in a physics book

$$\nabla\times\pmb{E}=\iiint_V\frac{\pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s}}{\lVert \pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s} \lVert^3}\rho(\pmb{r_s})d\tau\tag{2}$$

Here is the step I don't know how to justify

$$=k_e \iiint_V \nabla\times \left ( \frac{\pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s}}{\lVert \pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s} \lVert^3} \right )\rho(\pmb{r_s})d\tau\tag{3}$$

$$=0\tag{4}$$

I am fine with the final step: it results from the fact that $\nabla\times (r^n\hat{r})=0$. But why can the cross product pass through the triple integral?

Comment: Google Leibniz’s integral rule. THis allows you (under suitable hypotheses… which you always assume are satisfied in Physics) to interchange derivatives with integrals.

Answer (score 1):

The cross product only operates on terms in the integrand that are independent of the integration variable.
An example may help. Suppose we have a simpler one dimensional integral $I(x)$ where
$$I(x)=\int_{0}^{a}\left(x-x'\right)^2\,{\rm d}x'=
\int_{0}^{a}\left(x^2+x'^{\,2}-2x x'\right)\,{\rm d}x'$$
$$=x^2 a+a^3/3-x a^2.$$
Then taking the differentiation after the integration gives$$\dfrac{{\rm d}I(x)}{{\rm d}x}=2xa-a^2.......(1)$$
Now take the differential operator ${\rm d}/{\rm d}x$ inside the integral, and perform the differentiation before the integration, to get
$$ \dfrac{{\rm d}I(x)}{{\rm d}x}=\int_{0}^{a}\dfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}  \left( x^2+x'^{\,2}-2x x'\right)   \,{\rm d}x'   $$
$$=\int_{0}^{a} 2\left(x-x'\right)\,{\rm d}x'
=2xa-a^2. $$
in agreement with the differentiation in equation (1) above.

The differential operator, when taken inside the integral sign, only acts on those quantities, namely $x$, that are independent of the integration variable $x'$, and it does not change any of the quantities that depend on the integration variable itself.